# Tesseract quiet mode

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

Under Ubuntu I use tesseract-ocr in version 3.02. Especially the wrapper pytesseract for python, but this question is also about the commandline-tool.

In the FAQ under
https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_make_the_error_messages_go_to_tesseract.log_instead_of

is written that there is a option/config-file "quiet" supressing the info line of tesseract.

However, when I call tesseract command line with this option, it says

"read_params_file: Can't open quiet"

And it is right, in the corresponding config-folder there is no "quiet"-config-file.

Where can I get it or how can I create it?

The info-line which I want to supress is: "Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica".

Answer (score 1):

quiet is part of tesseract-ocr repository: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/tessdata/configs/quiet

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work. The output is stored in a debug_file but the info-line is still displayed in the terminal. I also tried this "debug_file"-parameter before without success.

Comment: First test:   
`c:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR>tesseract.exe testing\phototest.tif out`  
produce this:  
`Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica`  
  
Second test:  
`c:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR>tesseract.exe testing\phototest.tif out quiet`  
produce this:  
``  
  
Tested on Windows 7 64bit...

Comment: Maybe this works only for Windows. I have now added the option "1>/dev/null 2>&1" to the command. The info-line disappears if I call it in the terminal BUT with pytesseract this does not help :(

Answer (score 1):

The quiet config file from the other answer contains one line: `debug_file /dev/null`

If the config can't be used this way for some reason, you can achieve the same effect by adding `-c debug_file=/dev/null` somewhere before the input/output params.